# Fill values in another dataframe based on data from first one

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this:

```
ID  2018-01    2018-02   2018-03   2018-04
A1  8500        8500        8500      8500      
A2   NA         1900        1900      1900       
A3   NA          NA          NA       3000      
A4   NA          NA          NA          0
```

Now I have other dataframe that I want to use to fill NA values with

```
ID   Date    Due  
A1   2018-01  8500
A2   2018-01  9000
A3   2018-02  4000
A4   2018-01  1000
```

Now from the date in this dataframe (month) to the next value that is not na in the first dataframe I want to fill with the value from `Due` column:
So result is this:

```
ID  2018-01    2018-02   2018-03   2018-04
A1  8500        8500        8500      8500      
A2  9000        1900        1900      1900       
A3   NA         4000        4000      3000      
A4  1000        1000        1000         0
```

How could I do that?

**EDIT:**
There is a case when there are no prepopulated values in the row at all

```
    ID  2018-01    2018-02   2018-03   2018-04
    A1  8500        8500        8500      8500      
    A2   NA         1900        1900      1900       
    A3   NA          NA          NA       3000      
    A4   NA          NA          NA          0   
    A5   NA          NA          NA         NA


ID   Date    Due  
A1   2018-01  8500
A2   2018-01  9000
A3   2018-02  4000
A4   2018-01  1000
A5   2018-03  1500
```

In such a case is it possible to only put corresponding value in on column according to the date without filling it all the way ?

So the result:

```
 ID  2018-01    2018-02   2018-03   2018-04
A1  8500        8500        8500      8500      
A2  9000        1900        1900      1900       
A3   NA         4000        4000      3000      
A4  1000        1000        1000         0  
A5   NA          NA          1500       NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ID` is column in `df1` use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), then forward filling missin values, last replace missing values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) or [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df = df1.set_index('ID').fillna(df2.pivot('ID','Date','Due').ffill(axis=1))
print (df)
    2018-01  2018-02  2018-03  2018-04
ID                                    
A1   8500.0   8500.0   8500.0   8500.0
A2   9000.0   1900.0   1900.0   1900.0
A3      NaN   4000.0   4000.0   3000.0
A4   1000.0   1000.0   1000.0      0.0
A5      NaN      NaN   1500.0      NaN
```

Comment: There is some wierd behaviour with this solution when there are no values in a row in `df1`. Then the value added is negative and it fills all the way to the end. I edited the question to show expected behaviour.

Comment: @AlexT - Answer was edited. Please check if it is what you need.

Comment: I got error: `KeyError: "Cannot interpret 'ID' as period"` (this is after changing `ID` to index from being column in `df1`)

Comment: @AlexT - Use `df = df1.set_index('ID').fillna(df2.pivot('ID','Date','Due').ffill(axis=1))`

Answer (score 0):

Using `pd.crosstab` and `DataFrame.update`:

Since you want to update `NaN` values from one dataframe in another, we can use `DataFrame.update` for this, but first we set the right axis, since this method aligns on these:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('ID')
df1.update(pd.crosstab(df2['ID'], df2['Date'], df2['Due'], aggfunc='sum'))
df1 = df1.ffill(axis=1)

    2018-01  2018-02  2018-03  2018-04
ID                                    
A1   8500.0   8500.0   8500.0   8500.0
A2   9000.0   1900.0   1900.0   1900.0
A3      NaN   4000.0   4000.0   3000.0
A4   1000.0   1000.0   1000.0      0.0
```